# Is mounting BitLocker-encrypted drives an Ubuntu/Kubuntu feature or a Linux kernel thing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, bitlocker, kubuntu

Is the ability to mount BitLocker encrypted drives in the latest versions of Ubuntu and Kubuntu a *buntu feature or does it have to do directly with the Linux kernel?

In fact, I noticed that in Kubuntu 22.04 it is possible to mount these partitions without any problems, and when connecting a USB drive it automatically asks for the opening password.

Even the file manager respects the properties of folders created/modified in Windows, for example, if a folder is marked as "hidden", in Ubuntu/Kubuntu it also appears as hidden, unlike previous versions which ignored these properties.

Comment: `cryptsetup`'s recent advancements in Bitlocker support, probably. Properties of files/folders are completely independent from Bitlocker and unrelated though.

Answer (score 5):

> Is the ability to mount BitLocker encrypted drives in the latest versions of Ubuntu and Kubuntu a *buntu feature or does it have to do directly with the Linux kernel?

Neither. This feature was not added by Ubuntu specifically, but it also isn't a new kernel feature – it's the standard `cryptsetup` encrypted volume setup tool (more commonly used for LUKS) that learned how to recognize BitLocker metadata and mount such volumes through the kernel's *existing* `dm-crypt` facilities.

Handling of encrypted volumes on Linux is usually split across two programs: cryptsetup deals with volume metadata (passwords, keyslots, etc.) while the kernel only takes a raw AES key and an offset into a device.

This separation allows the same dm-crypt kernel subsystem to be used by several different encryption tools regardless of format. (For example, the official TrueCrypt app relies on dm-crypt as well, and there already were tools to open BitLocker via dm-crypt long before Cryptsetup gained support for that. There were no kernel changes for Cryptsetup's migration from LUKS1 to LUKS2 either.)

None of the above features are specific to Ubuntu – even though cryptsetup is not part of the kernel, it is nevertheless part of the "standard" Linux tool set that is common across nearly all Linux distributions.

> Even the file manager respects the properties of folders created/modified in Windows, for example, if a folder is marked as "hidden", in Ubuntu/Kubuntu it also appears as hidden, unlike previous versions which ignored these properties.

This has nothing to do with BitLocker. Files, folders, and their attributes are managed by the *file system* – typically NTFS for Windows, ext4 for Ubuntu – which behaves the same way no matter what kind of storage it's put on.

Hiding files is partly a kernel feature and partly a userspace program feature, as even the latest Linux kernel doesn't have anything like a "hidden" attribute at OS level – so even though the Linux NTFS driver can read the "hidden" flag from disk, it has no way of providing that to programs in a standard way.

(It does expose the DOS attributes through Linux's generic "extended attribute" facility, but this method has several problems – it's filesystem-specific and makes listing files a bit slower – so it's only used by very few programs.)

So the most likely difference is that recent Linux kernel versions do come with a new NTFS driver (ntfs3, vs the older ntfs-3g), and among other differences the new driver honors the "hidden" flag on its own and *completely* skips hidden files when listing entries in a directory – which actually makes them stay hidden even if "Show hidden files" is checked, because the file manager is not in control of it anymore.

But another possible difference is that the KDE file manager decided to pay attention to the NTFS-specific "DOSATTRIB" attribute, hiding files without requiring any kernel changes.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and sorry about the file/folder properties part, maybe the excitement of knowing about these changes in Ubuntu and not finding an official announcement or changelog about it.